# rpm package conflicts with itself in yum

Tags: yum, rpm, specfile

I prepared custom package **platform-6-1.2.3-1.x86_64**.

I want it to be conflicting with every OTHER **plat-6** package installed in the system.
Files of the package are not conflicting with the others plat-6 packages.

So I filled in spec file with:

```
Name: platform-6
Provides: plat-6
Conflicts: plat-6
```

Now, when I install the package on the system, sometimes I get this:

```
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
platform-6-1.2.3-1.x86_64 has installed conflicts plat-6: platform-6-1.2.3-1.x86_64
Error: check all
```

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I wanted it to be conflicting with any OTHER package which has `Provides: plat-6` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is

```
Provides: plat-6
```

You are making it conflict with itself.

EDIT:

Try

```
Conflicts:          plat-6 < %{version}
```

Comment: Sure, because it provides that capability, which is different from pkg name.But how to make it conflict with any other package providing that capability?

Comment: set a version less then the current one you are creating

Comment: see my edit for a conflicts with a version